# React.js export async function

Tags: reactjs, async-await, weather-api

I'm new to React.js, so please bear with me on this one.

I built a weather API app with react.js and it works. The one thing I can't do is have my `async function fetchData(e)` exported such that I can access it from any component outside the scope of App.js.
How do I export async fetchData so that it is recognized by all components that reside outside of App.js?
Do note that the `async function fetchData(e)` function needs all the variables that are declared at the beginning of App.js.

I excluded my API Key from the code for obvious reasons, and I didn't include all of the code inside the fetchData function because it's very lengthy.

```js
function App() {
  //Variables
  const API_KEY = '';
  const METRE_SECOND_TO_KM_HR = 3.6;
  const DAYS = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  const options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
  };

  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);
  const [geolocation, setGeolocation] = useState([]);

  async function fetchData(e) {
    //async function fetchData(e) {
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const state = e.target.elements.state.value;
    const country = e.target.elements.country.value;

    e.preventDefault();
    //fetch request with city, state and country - to get a latitude and longitude based on city name.
    const geolocation_api_request_url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${city},${state},${country}&limit=5&appid=${API_KEY}`;
    await fetch(geolocation_api_request_url)
      .then(function (res) {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        if (city && state && country) {
          //set the latitude and longitude of the location
          setGeolocation({
            data: data,
            lat: data[0].lat,
            lon: data[0].lon,
          });
          //make a second fetch call, this time with latitude and longitude
          const weather_api_url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${geolocation.lat}&lon=${geolocation.lon}&exclude=minutely,hourly&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`;
          return fetch(weather_api_url);
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component

have a look at this context Api of react js by using this you can get this function in any component in your application and you can also update the values of it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do as the following.

-- WeatherAPI.js --

```
const fetchData = (city, state, country, setGeolocation) => {
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject)=>{
        const geolocation_api_request_url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${city},${state},${country}&limit=5&appid=${API_KEY}`;
        try{
            res = await fetch(geolocation_api_request_url);
            if(city && state && country){
                //set the latitude and longitude of the location
                const data = res.json();
                setGeolocation && setGeolocation({
                    data: data,
                    lat: data[0].lat,
                    lon: data[0].lon,
                });
                
                //make a second fetch call, this time with latitude and longitude
                const weather_api_url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${geolocation.lat}&lon=${geolocation.lon}&exclude=minutely,hourly&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`;
                resolve(await fetch(weather_api_url));
             }
         }catch(e){
             reject(e);
         }
    });
}
export fetchData;
```

--- App.js ---

```
import {fetchData} from '../api/WeatherAPI";
...
function fetchDataFromGoogle(e) {
   ...
   (async()=>{
       try{
           const weatherData = await fetchData(city, state, country, setGeolocation);
       }catch(e){
           console.error(e);
       }
   })();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export async functions as such, once you seperate it from the App function:

```
export const fetchData = async (args) => {
// Your implementation

}
```

As to the parameters, if they are all constants put them inside a json object and pass to the function, as exported function can't access those variables:

```
const args = {
    API_KEY : '',
    METRE_SECOND_TO_KM_HR : 3.6,
    DAYS : ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    options : {
      weekday: 'long',
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'long',
      day: 'numeric',
}
```

and pass this object to the function as parameter:

```
export const fetchData = async (e, args) => {
    // Your implementation
    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried doing the export like that, I get this error:'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (44:2)2)

Comment: this cannot work because you are already in app function

Comment: oh my bad was lazy paying attention, yeah you need to seperate the two unfortunately

Comment: Thank you Sinan, its okay, would you mind explaining why it wouldn't work? I don't understand why it wouldn't work to export it inside the App.js.

Comment: Because it is a function inside another function, you can only export if it is not inside a scope, meaning when it is at the top level.